# how to call swapETHforexactToken in https://goerli.etherscan.io/

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, goerli

first of i deployed a contract address in the  https://goerli.etherscan.io/ and i use the uniswap v2 router2 (0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D) in my contract. the token address of the my deployed contract is "https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x668f8EA02F749E40268C4e4B4550319DDb1Ef252" and also
i created a LP by using the https://app.uniswap.org/ for this new token I've created. now when i am using the address https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D#writeContract for calling the swapETHforexactToken i got the problem gas estimation problem in my metamask how can i solve this ,
i provided the infomration i provided in the https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D#writeContract in text and image

thanks in advance

swapETHForExactTokens
0,000001
amountOut (uint256)
0
path (address[])
["0x668f8EA02F749E40268C4e4B4550319DDb1Ef252","0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6"]
to (address)
0xf3421eD804ae6fD97f86171765aaf23a4C38b5eF
deadline (uint256)
1705158694
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two problem on your smart contract execution

1. You set the wrong "path". Basically, swapETHforExactTokens requires the path to be from "WETH" to "Tokens". Therefore, the first index of path should be "WETH". However, in your execution, you place the "WETH" at the second index. Thus, in order to fix the problem, you've just need to reverse the "path" like this

```
["0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6","0x668f8EA02F749E40268C4e4B4550319DDb1Ef252"]
```

2. I double check your token liquidity in testnet. However, they have zero liquidity with WETH. Therefore, it would be better for you to check again the addLiquidity function if it success or not.